# Как защитить xml от запросов с других сайтов?

Tags: xml, ajax, php, javascript

Как защитить xml от запросов с других сайтов? XML сделан на php, т.е. расширение и язык php. Можно ли как-то защитить от других сайтов этот файл? Может, как-то через пароль, хотя его можно увидеть в исходном коде, если речь идёт об Ajax. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте авторизацию при помощи сессий.

Comment: Спасибо, а какие-то ещё есть способы? Бд не предлагать, сам догадался)

Comment: Возможно Вы криво сформулировали вопрос. Уточните.

Если Вы не хотите, чтобы javascript с другого сайта мог обращаться к Вашему -- это настройка безопасности по умолчанию.

В любом случае уточните вопрос.

Comment: Ну у меня при нажатии на кнопку ajax`ом посылаются данные на обработчик, который как раз хочу защитить.
И всё-таки не понял, ты предлагаешь при заходе на страничку, которая будет обращаться к обработчику создавать сессию, а в обработчике проверить если существует то выполнить всё что надо и удалить сессию. Ну а если он сделает свой обработчик, который сначала будет открывать ту страницу, а потом уже отправлять запрос на мой обработчик?

Comment: Я предлагаю _подробней_ расписать проблему. На данный момент вижу как минимум 3 варианта трактовки проблемы. Проще Вам уточнить, чем мне расписать решения всех 3-х.

Comment: Проблема в том, что нужно защитить обработчик от посторонних запросов, запросы отправлю ajax`ом. Чтобы никто ,кроме моего сайта не смог получить нужный ответ от обработчика. И ещё я не понял что вы подразумеваете под "авторизацию при помощи сессий".

Answer (score 1):

Проверяй `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - это может в чем-то помочь тоже.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` возвращает `NULL`.

Comment: ну если запрос с вашего сервера Ajax-ом,то там будет не пусто. Значить если Null -  то exit();

Comment: Я уже много тестировал `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, возвращает `null` даже при запросе ajax-ом. Уточню метод отправки: `xmlHttp.open`